# System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension does not trim a file path

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

Function `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` does not trim a file path when I use .Net 5 compiler.

Example:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"C:\test\temp123.yaml");
```

Returns:

```
C:\test\temp123
```

Comment: [How to reproduce it](https://ibb.co/m6YsFcC)

Comment: No repro *on Windows*. What OS did you try this on? BTW if what you claim was true on *Windows*, hundreds of thousands of developers would have noticed 19 years ago

Comment: Hey @PanagiotisKanavos, I posted a picture in the previous comment that illustrates the issue.

Comment: Images from dotnetfiddle aren't reproducible. Image isn't code. The actual link to the fiddle would be useful but even then, the only way to get the result you posted is for the string to contain characters that look like a backslash but aren't

Comment: [No repro on dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zc2V3s) for .NET 4.7.2 or Roslyn 3.8. .NET 5 produces what you posted which means *the site uses Linux for that target*. On Linux, `\\` isn't a path separator, it's part of the name. If you run this .NET 5 code on *Windows* you'll get the expected behavior

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos here is a link to the example on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oupT11)

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine(Environment.OSVersion.ToString());` to see why.

Comment: Seems strange that dotNetFiddle would use Linux for only one of the environments, which is bound to create strange discrepancies such as this.

Comment: Anyway, things like this are **exactly** why you need to check things like the `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead of blindly assuming that a given filename will Just Work.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to get this result is to use .NET Core or Mono on Linux.

If you run this code on dotNetFiddle [targeting .NET 4.7.2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vpKN3F) :

```
public static void Main()
{
    var name=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"c:\test\temp123.yaml");
    Console.WriteLine(name);
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
}
```

You'll get :

```
temp123
Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
```

If you try [.NET (Core) 5](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GyXRy5) though, you'll get:

```
c:\test\temp123
Unix 5.4.0.1036
```